# .net 4 and entity framework 5.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 in .net 4. Currently planning to upgrade to Entity Framework 5.0. As far as googled, i could see that only very minimal features are supported in .net 4.0 for entity framework 5.0.

My expectation in upgrading to EF5.0 is to acheive the runtime performance improvements. Will i achieve these improvements when upgrading to EF5.0 in .net 4.?

I will start using the .net 4.5 framework in the near future. So does it worth now for me to upgrade to EF5.0 in .net 4 now/ it will go in vein when moving to .net 4.5? Or is it better to upgrade to EF5.0 when moving to .net 4.5?

Thanx

Comment: You need .net 4.5 to harness the performance benefits from EF 5.

Comment: in EF4 and EF5 query pipeline lives in System.Data.Entity.dll that is part of the .NET Framework. So, you won't see the perf improvements from introduced in EF5 until you move to .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using EF 4.0 and `ObjectContext` you will get any benefit only when upgrading to .NET 4.5. EF 4.1 - EF 4.4 (EF 5.0 for .NET 4.0) are mostly about new API and DbContext API so unless you want to change the API you will not have any benefit. All performance improvements are dependent on class library which is currently part of .NET Framework so you will not have those improvements without upgrading to .NET 4.5. This will change with EF 6 (it will be first version released with all EF libraries).